# Load chart series as regarding the present Month

Tags: c#

I have insert a chart on my windows form with 12 series named;January,February,Mars....December. I wish to display the series as regarding the present or actual month. that is, if the actual month of the year is January, it should load an present the series January. if it is February, it should and present the series February and so on.
presently my chart load all the series when i execute the program. 
Please i need Assistance. Thank

'

```
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            chart1Ind_Ponc_cam.Series["Janvier"].Points.AddXY(reader["Jour"].ToString(), reader["Janvier"].ToString());
            chart1Ind_Ponc_cam.Series["Février"].Points.AddXY(reader["Jour"].ToString(), reader["Février"].ToString());
            chart1Ind_Ponc_cam.Series["Mars"].Points.AddXY(reader["Jour"].ToString(), reader["Mars"].ToString());
            chart1Ind_Ponc_cam.Series["Avril"].Points.AddXY(reader["Jour"].ToString(), reader["Avril"].ToString());
            chart1Ind_Ponc_cam.Series["Mai"].Points.AddXY(reader["Jour"].ToString(), reader["Mai"].ToString());
            chart1Ind_Ponc_cam.Series["Juin"].Points.AddXY(reader["Jour"].ToString(), reader["Juin"].ToString());
            chart1Ind_Ponc_cam.Series["Juillet"].Points.AddXY(reader["Jour"].ToString(), reader["Juillet"].ToString());
            chart1Ind_Ponc_cam.Series["Août"].Points.AddXY(reader["Jour"].ToString(), reader["Aout"].ToString());
            chart1Ind_Ponc_cam.Series["Septembre"].Points.AddXY(reader["Jour"].ToString(), reader["Septembre"].ToString());
            chart1Ind_Ponc_cam.Series["Octobre"].Points.AddXY(reader["Jour"].ToString(), reader["Octobre"].ToString());
            chart1Ind_Ponc_cam.Series["Novembre"].Points.AddXY(reader["Jour"].ToString(), reader["Novembre"].ToString());
            chart1Ind_Ponc_cam.Series["Décembre"].Points.AddXY(reader["Jour"].ToString(), reader["Décembre"].ToString());

        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ICh6.png)
`

Comment: You have a choice of loading all and only display one (by setting `series.Enabled = false/true`) or of actually loading only one. This is so simple that I really don't know what you are asking?! Simply prefix each AddXY with a condition like `if (DatTime.Now.Month == ..)` )

Comment: Thank you very much. Its helpful